# Can't import pandas into pycharm interpreter, despite changing pyCharm python interpreter path

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I'm trying to import pandas in the pyCharm python interpreter, but I keep on getting the dreaded

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

It works fine when I run python from the terminal. I've read up on solutions for this, but none have worked so far. 
I've pip uninstalled, reinstalled, and updated pandas. I've changed the pyCharm project python interpreter and default pyCharm python interpreter to be "2.7.5 (/usr/local/bin/python)", so that now:

```
>>> os.system('which python')
/usr/local/bin/python
```

occurs in the pycharm interpreter and terminal python interpreter.

Any more ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I see a mismatch `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/python`, is that a typo?

Comment: well it would be rude to argue with you ;)

Comment: @Padriac :) hehe - that wasn't a typo, I was just wrong, durp! Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed that interpreter paths so they were indeed the same, but that didn't actually fix things. However, changing the terminal shell path ended up fixed everything! :) will add as answer.

Comment: No worries, it is one of the many joys of have a couple of python 2 installations!

Comment: Your Anaconda interpreter can't be your Pycharm interpreter. they must vary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out, changing my terminal shell path in pyCharms settings (In the menu bar, pyCharm --> Preferences --> tools --> terminal --> Shell Path) to the correct thing:

```
> echo $PATH # whatever this spits out in terminal is your shell path
```

fixed everything :)

Comment: I tried this and got /Users/MyName/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin. Does my Anaconda installation look wrong? Pycharm is still not seeting mathplotlib or pandas for me.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the project interpreter under PyCharm -> Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter to the one that that of my system uses. I had 2.6 and 2.7 in the system and PyCharm was using 2.6 by default. Changed it to 2.7 which is what the Terminal was using. Problem solved.

Comment: I tried this and got /Users/MyName/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin. Does my Anaconda installation look wrong? Pycharm is still not seeting mathplotlib or pandas for me.

Comment: This worked for me. The previous interpreter was at version 2.6.9, and that did not have pandas included when I installed the pandas via pip. So I switched to 2.7.9 which had the pandas installed. Thanks :)