# Python packages not importing in PyCharm despite correct interpreter

Tags: python, import, package, pycharm, interpreter

I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<package>'` for any package that I try to import in all new projects.

I read that problem usually means I'm not using the correct interpreter, so I ran `pip3 show <package>` to find the location (it's in the same one as all the other packages), copied the path name and made a new interpreter in `PyCharm > Settings > Python Interpreter > Show All > Show paths for the selected interpret > Add`.

After this, I get the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<package>'` and I noticed that when I added the path name for interpreter, `/bin/python` got added on at the end. Is this expected?

I also tried copying the output from `echo $PATH` to terminal shell path in settings, like the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640911/cant-import-pandas-into-pycharm-interpreter-despite-changing-pycharm-python-in), and that didn't work either.

What else can I try so importing packages works? Is it something with the settings when I create new projects?

I'm using Python 3.9.13

Comment: The `pip3` that you ran is definitely not belong to the same `python` that PyCharm is running.  Please verify that the output of `import sys; print(sys.executable);print(sys.prefix)` point to the expected Python interpreter (and environment) for your project under PyCharm.

Comment: Go to File|settings|Project|Python interpreter. Do your modules appear under packages? If not, you are not using the interpreter you think you are. Press the '+' and install the modules you want from the pop-up window.

Comment: What happens if you try importing a standard library module, such as `sys`, from your Pycharm project? Assuming that works, what result do you get for `sys.path`? Does it include the path that `pip` told you about? Does it include any paths that look related to the interpreter path that you set?

Comment: @metatoaster it gave 2 outputs, one of which is the location of pip3 show <package> and another is the same but with '/bin/python' at the end.

Comment: Copy the path produced by `sys.executable`, use that to start an interactive shell, and try to import that package, or use that python and add `-m pip install <package>` and see if that actually fix it.

Comment: i get `command not found: -m`